# Problems with subtraction of a float number

Tags: c++, c

This program have to count minimum number of coins, but it has some kind of bug because results are weird. It`s probably obvious mistake but I cant find it.

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
      float x;
      printf("How much cash in float number:");
      scanf("%f", &x);

      int quaters;
      while(x>=0.25){
        x-=0.25;
        quaters++;
      }
      printf("%f\n",x);

      int fives;
      while (x>=0.05){
        x-=0.05;
        fives++;
      }
       printf("%f\n",x);

      int one;
      while (x>=0.01){
        x-=0.01;
        one++;
      }
       printf("%f\n",x);
      printf("quaters %d\t fives %d\t ones %d\n", quaters, fives, one);
      return 0;
    }
```

And the output is this

```
    How much cash in float number:0.41
0.160000
0.010000
0.010000
quaters 1    fives 3     ones 32764
```

What`s wrong?

Comment: Where and how do you initialze `quarter`, `fives`, `ones`? And [tag:C++] and [tag:C] are not the same thing! this is just [tag:C].

Comment: When dealing with cash, it's usually better to tink in terms of pennies and use integers, so 101 cents rather than 1.01 dollars. That will get rid of the issues with floating-point comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize `quaters`, `fives` and `one` to 0 before using it:

```
int quaters=0;
....
int fives=0;
....
int one=0;
....
```

Regarding the last 0.01 result, google for "comparing float variables C++". Even here in SO you will find plenty of related posts.

For immediate solution, since you use up to 2 digits after the decimal point, change `float` compare from

```
x>=0.25
```

to

```
x>0.249
```

And all the others accordingly:

```
x>0.049

x>0.009
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int quaters;
int fives;
int one;
```

`quaters` `fives` and `one` is uninitialized which will lead to undefined behavior

Answer (score 0):

`quarter` ,`five` and `one` are uninitalized . Initialize them to `0`.

Also in comparisons -

```
  while(x>=0.25){        // x is float and 0.25 is double 
    x-=0.25;
```

You should not compare float numbers like this .

Answer (score 0):

Try using small value to compare to hide the error. Let me use `EPS` here as the small value.

- `a>b` -> `a>b+EPS`
- `a>=b` -> `a+EPS>b`
- `a==b` -> `fabs(a-b)<EPS` (`fabs` is in `math.h`)

Also, don't forget to initialize the variables!

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define EPS (1e-9)

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    float x;
    printf("How much cash in float number:");
    scanf("%f", &x);

    int quaters=0;
    while(x+EPS>0.25){
        x-=0.25;
        quaters++;
    }
    printf("%f\n",x);

    int fives=0;
    while (x+EPS>0.05){
        x-=0.05;
        fives++;
    }
    printf("%f\n",x);

    int one=0;
    while (x+EPS>0.01){
        x-=0.01;
        one++;
    }
    printf("%f\n",x);
    printf("quaters %d\t fives %d\t ones %d\n", quaters, fives, one);
    return 0;
}
```